# How to connect MySQL to PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm brand spanking new to mysql and php.

I'm set up with Mysql workbench and I'm practicing building a site using Notepad++ and just run it through Chrome.  All I want to do is create a sign up page, which I'm assuming I use a .php page on the site, where it would be a username and password.  That's it.  I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to connect mysql to the .php page, or how to create a sign in page.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: pls avoid w3schools.com, and  use php.net for full coverage ...

Comment: Try google.com; use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: these kind of questions looks like to promote other sites, as point of SEO or some other reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to PHP!

Typically a connection is established on a PHP page with something along the lines of this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","[username]","[password]","[databasename]") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
```

The "or die" will produce an error if there's a problem establishing a connection. Also, this uses the newer "mysqli_" method for connection; make sure when you call this connection in future that you use mysqli_ methods (there are still traditional "mysql_" methods available, but are depreciated).

Hope this helps!

M

Answer (score -2):

here you go you, here you can find a way to properly connect to the database as well as all the data you  need to get set up with your signup form

http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-sign-up-form-registration-with-php-and-mysql/28675

Comment: Seems like more of a comment than an answer.